# Another instance of BOINC manager is already running... - what is the client/password?

Tags: boinc

I closed (or thought I had closed) the BOINC manager, without ending the tasks. When I opened the manager again to administer the tasks, I was presented with a dialog saying "Another instance of BOINC manager is already running on this computer. Please select a client to monitor", and asked for a host name and password.

What do I enter to make it connect to the client that is (presumably) still running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused because the `boincmgr` process was not ended when the manager was closed, as evidenced by `ps -e | grep boinc` showing the manager (and the `boinc` process) still running though the window was closed.

Assuming you didn't set it up otherwise, the host name to connect to the existing one is `localhost` and the password is blank.